# What is the best way to upload video frames generated by Opencv to GPU?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I am currently working on simulating a dvs camera on an input video file.
I currently read the video frame by frame and send each frame to GPU to do some calculation on it.

The thing I'm interested in doing is send all the frames ( or atleast as much as there is memory available in GPU ) to GPU first, then handle all the computation.

I am using Mat to store the data and upload it to GPU.

Maybe an array of Mats could be sent to GPU? but I don't know how to do that.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your computation based on opencv's cuda functions or a custom kernel?

Comment: Take a look here http://answers.opencv.org/question/89050/passing-an-array-of-cvgpumat-to-a-cuda-kernel/ . Also note that OpenCV already supports operations on GPU, so you may not need to create your own CUDA kernel https://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html .

Comment: I could not get opencv to work with cuda 9.1. seems like it doesn't support GPU computations for the newer versions.
and I am trying to learn parallel programming so I want to write it myself.

Comment: @Aram It's not based on opencv's cuda functions. I am trying to do it myself.

Comment: Then you should use something like this with your data pointers of the mats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835537/cuda-allocating-array-of-arrays